# Save select array into Wordpress user meta

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, forms

I am making a custom form for users to edit their profile information on WordPress... I have the below code which creates a multiple select box of options:

```
<label for="industryinterest"><?php _e('Industry of Interest', 'profile'); ?></label>

<p>Current selection: <?php the_author_meta( 'industryinterest', $current_user->ID ); ?></p>

<select name="industryinterest[]" multiple size="5" id="industryinterest">
  <option value="Agriculture">Agriculture</option>
  <option value="Consumer">Consumer</option>
  <option value="Energy">Energy</option>
  <option value="Financial Services">Financial Services</option>
  <option value="Healthcare">Healthcare</option>
  <option value="Manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
  <option value="Nightlife">Nightlife</option>
  <option value="Philanthropic">Philanthropic</option>
  <option value="Property">Property</option>
  <option value="Restaurants">Restaurants</option>
  <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
  <option value="Science">Science</option>
  <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
  <option value="Telecommunications">Telecommunications</option>
  <option value="Transport">Transport</option>
</select>
```

And I have the below code that I am using to save the data from this multiple select box to a custom meta called "industryinterest"

```
  if ( !empty( $_POST['industryinterest'] ) )
        update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'industryinterest', esc_attr( $_POST['industryinterest'][0] ) );
```

It works well, and saves the data but it only ever saves one selection.

How would I get this code to save multiple selections into the one custom meta called "industryinterest" - maybe have them separated by a slash or comma?

I've added the [] from researching online about arrays but it isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

Data in wpdb shoud be stored as json type , so try to json_encode your $_POST array data and update your usermeta .

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How exactly would I do that?

Comment: $json_data = json_encode($_POST['industryinterest']); try this if your $_POST variable is array type

Comment: Format your array data like this $args = ['1'=>'a','2'=>'b']; $args = json_encode($args); then update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'industryinterest', $args );